Json result returning as empty
I wrote a method to get the stringified json as output but since it was blocking the UI i wrote this inside a timeout.
now i'm getting the result as empty in UI.
i want the json to show up without blocking while JSON.stringify is happening.
code:
handleJsonViewerOpen(): void {
    this.jsonView = true;
    this.loading = true;
    this.showMonacoEditor();
  }

  showMonacoEditor(): void {
    setImmediate(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.showEditor = true;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }, 300);
    });
  }
  jsonstringify(): string {
    this.loading = false;
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
    let result: string = '';
    setTimeout(() => {
      result = JSON.stringify(this.data, null, '\t');
    }, 0);
      return result;
    }

html section for the ts:
<button
  id="btnGetJson"
  pButton
  icon="fa fa-file-code-o"
  pTooltip="Json Viewer"
  tooltipPosition="bottom"
  class="p-button-secondary"
  (click)="handleJsonViewerOpen()"
></button>
<p-dialog
  [(visible)]="jsonView"
  header="Json Viewer({{ header }})"
  positionTop="0"
  styleClass="custom-dialog"
  responsive="true"
  [closable]="false"
>
  <loader [visible]="loading" *ngIf="!jsonViewerLoader"></loader>
  <div *ngIf="showEditor">
    <ngx-codemirror [ngModel]="jsonstringify()" [options]="editorOptions"> </ngx-codemirror>
  </div>


Yeah. Your setTimeout callback will happen sometime later after return result is already done.

@Askyy please raise a question on what you want to achieve by doing this code, there is no need for JSON.stringify and this extra code bits, please raise a simple stackblitz with a problem happpening and what you need fixed, its best for debugging
